# Visual Studio 2022 - Debug Managed Memory stops at 'X object found'

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

When trying to analyze a memory dump file after starting 'Debug Managed Memory' my VS stacks at 'X objects found' - always same number which seems to be much smaller than count of real objects on the heaps.

[image]

Do you have any ideas how to get the information why it stops or any workaround?

There are no information about any problems in the output window.

I've tried to load a dump for the same application (Blazor Server Side) from QA server and this time it stops with a message '132 000 000 objects loaded. The memory usage of the laptop is very small - about 2GB, dump file itself is about 8GB.

Thanks a lot for any help!